# Vue watcher triggering in data() change

Tags: vue.js

```
    <script>
export default {
  name: "DriversStandings",

  data() {
    return {
      standingsData: [],
    };
  },

  props: ["drivers", "isUpdated"],

  watch: {
    drivers: {
      deep: true,
      handler: function () {
        this.test();
      },
    },
  },

  methods:{
    test(){
      console.log("chamou o teste")
      this.standingsData = this.drivers
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I am getting a bit crazy. Isn't the watcher supposed to watch only for "drivers" prop? It somehow is triggering when i edit "standingsData too, making me unable to sort it. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2):

This may depend on how you're sorting the array, but since you assign `this.standingsData = this.drivers` any **mutating** changes to `this.standingsData` will also mutate data under `this.drivers` since they reference the same array. You probably want to make a *copy* of the drivers array to put into component state, something like this:

```js
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log("chamou o teste")
      this.standingsData = [...this.drivers];
    }
  }
```

Keep in mind that mutating other data deeply within `this.standingsData` will also have similar problems because you specify `deep: true` on the watcher; if you must do this you'll want to **deeply** copy data when moving `this.drivers` into `this.standingsData`. This can be done with custom code, or tools like [lodash.cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep).

Another quirk here is that Vue watchers won't trigger upon component initialization by default. You'll need to add `immediate: true` to the watcher if you want it to trigger ever time the `drivers` prop changes *and* when it's initially set during component init (docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch)).

```js
  watch: {
    drivers: {
      deep: true,
      immediate: true,
      handler: function () {
        this.test();
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: TAHNK YOU SOO MUCH. I still don't understand very well what was happening. I thought that "this.standingsData = this.drivers" would make the copy of "this.drivers" to this.standingsData and i am still confused why it isn't the case. any resources that could elaborate why is not?

Comment: No problem! The underlying reason why a copy is not made here has to do with JavaScript more than Vue – similar to JavaScript functions, primitive values for Vue props are "passed by value" into the child component, but Object/Array values are "passed by reference" (the "note" at the bottom of this section in the docs describes this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow). Here's a much better answer than mine which goes into more depth about similar subject matter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61698192/11776945

Comment: I am still having problems. This block of code is still mutating parents state:computed: {
    sortedList() {
      let array = [...this.drivers];
      array.map((x) =>{
        x.points = parseFloat( x.gainedPoints) + parseFloat( x.points)
      })
      let sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => { return b.points - a.points})
      return sortedArray;
    },
  },

Comment: i made a new question asking for further help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70118785/why-this-computed-property-still-mutate-parents-state

Comment: You're unfortunately still mutating the data inside the array with `array.map((x) =>{ x.points = parseFloat( ... ) })`. This happens because `this.standingsData = [...this.drivers];` does a "shallow" copy (only copying the outer array, not internal objects); as opposed to something like lodash.cloneDeep (mentioned above) which performs a "deep" copy. With the shallow copy, the mutations will still affect data in parent. To modify this data without mutating it, you want something like: `array = array.map((x) => { return { ...x, points: parseFloat( x.gainedPoints) + parseFloat( x.points) }; });`

Comment: i resolved it with deep clone. But boy... how can vue's docs not discuss this topic deeper than with a single note? Insane that the cleanest way to deal with it is by using external tools

Comment: Agreed this is a footgun Vue should call out more clearly in the docs. But I think the problem is one you'll run into with JavaScript code in general. It's the same as if you passed your data into a function – mutating that input data _within_ the function for whatever reason will result in bugs as external references to that data inadvertently change. A rule of thumb is: any time you mutate input data, you _must_ copy it first in some way or another. Even better would be to avoid mutating it altogether (through "immutable" data management techniques such as the alternative array.map above).