# Why this computed property still mutate parents state?

Tags: vue.js

```
computed: {
    sortedList() {
      let array = [...this.drivers];
      array.map((x) =>{
        x.points = parseFloat( x.gainedPoints) + parseFloat( x.points)
      })
      let sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => { return b.points - a.points})
      return sortedArray;
    },
  },
```

I am getting crazy with this. Even after copying the array with [...this.Drivers] the computed property still changes parent's data, resulting in x.points getting bigger and bigger after each time sortedList is called. How can i prevent it? I know that:

*Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself inside the child component will affect parent state.*

But still i can't find a way to avoid mutating parent's data.

Comment: Where is `drivers` defined?

Comment: it's a prop recieved from parents component

Comment: Post that code too. It's needed for debugging. Also, it sounds like it's coming from a store, so you might want to post that too.

Comment: As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/q/70116331/11776945, try modifying your array data without mutating each item within it: `array = array.map((x) => { return { ...x, points: parseFloat( x.gainedPoints) + parseFloat( x.points) }; });`

Comment: Because of this, `x.points =`.

Comment: You're copying the array but not the items within it. When you do `x.points =` you're modifying the original array item.